# Most influential samples in correlation

Tags: regression, correlation

I know there is this concept of "most influential points" in regression, and I am wondering whether there is such a concept for correlation as well, which is a symmetric metric unlike regression -- i.e., there is no "independent" vs "dependent" variable in correlation. Obviously there is no "fit line", either, in correlation, but intuitively there should be a way to find the samples that has the most influence in the correlation statistic or p-value. Is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correlation isn't a good measure for non-linear relationships, so I'll answer this question in a general setting. Suppose you have a dependence measure $I(X,Y)$ where $X=\{x_1,\dots, x_n\}$ are the inputs and $Y=\{y_1,\dots, y_n\}$ are the outputs. High values of $I(\cdot, \cdot)$ means that dependence is likely, near zero values mean independence $x\perp y$.

Denote $X_{-i}$ and $Y_{-i}$ the datasets obtained by removing the points $x_i, y_i$ associated with index $i$.

Your goal seems to be the following:

> Find index $i$ so that removing the $i$-th point maximally impacts the similarity between  the new datasets $X_{-i}, Y_{-i}$.

Or more formally: you want to find $\max_i \lvert S(X,Y) - S(X_{-i}, Y_{-i})\rvert$.

This can easily be done by brute force if the number of points $n$ is small ($n\leq 10^4)$, you just compute for every $i$ the difference $\Delta_i =\lvert S(X,Y) - S(X_{-i}, Y_{-i})\rvert$ and output $i^\star$ the index which maximises $\Delta_i$.